# GEE cycle if for skip the null value from Modis "'Day_view_time'" band

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis, function

I trying to take the time value from Modis band and convert it from local solar time to UTC. After I need to concatenate it with date which I take from system;time_start and print all statistics. After print sts variable is String (Error) Number.floor: Parameter 'input' is required. If try to print stats - Invalid string length. I think a problem inside If cycle because continue to print time variable with null value.

```
var mod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1");
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(-116.0199,36.62418);
var buffer = point.buffer(564.2);
var collection = mod.filterBounds(buffer)
                            .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-01-01')
                            .select(['LST_Day_1km', 'Day_view_time']);

var filtered_scaled = collection.map(function(image) {
var buffer = point.buffer(564.2);
var time = image.select('Day_view_time').multiply(0.1).add(8).copyProperties(image);
var lst = image.select('LST_Day_1km').multiply(0.02).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start', 'system:index']);
return image.addBands(time, null, true)
              .addBands(lst, null, true)
              .clip(buffer)});
              
var nImages = filtered_scaled.size();
var ImageList = filtered_scaled.toList(nImages);
var img_indices = ee.List.sequence(0,nImages.subtract(1)).getInfo();

function reduceAndPrint(index) {
  var nomScale = filtered_scaled.select('LST_Day_1km').first().projection().nominalScale();
  var nomScale2 = filtered_scaled.select('Day_view_time').first().projection().nominalScale();
  var buffer = point.buffer(564.2); // CALCULATION LST BUFFER
  var image = ee.Image(ImageList.get(index));
  var TmeanDay = image.select('Day_view_time').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    scale: nomScale2,
    geometry: buffer
  });    

  var time = TmeanDay.get('Day_view_time');
    //print('time', time);
  var hours = ee.Number(time).floor().divide(1).int();
  var minutes = ee.Number(time).subtract(hours).multiply(60).round().int();
  var result = hours.format('%02d').cat(':').cat(minutes.format('%02d')).cat(':00');
      if (result !== null) {
       var systemTimeStart = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd ');
       var sts = ee.String(systemTimeStart).cat(ee.String(result));
       //print('sts:', sts);
       var date = image.get('system:index');
      return [sts,date];
      } else{ return null; } } 
      
var stats = img_indices.map(reduceAndPrint); 
print(stats);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is related to following lines inside your **reduceAndPrint** function:

```
var time = TmeanDay.get('Day_view_time');
    //print('time', time);
  var hours = ee.Number(time).floor().divide(1).int();
  var minutes = ee.Number(time).subtract(hours).multiply(60).round().int();
  var result = hours.format('%02d').cat(':').cat(minutes.format('%02d')).cat(':00');
      if (result !== null) {
       var systemTimeStart = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd ');
       var sts = ee.String(systemTimeStart).cat(ee.String(result));
       //print('sts:', sts);
       var date = image.get('system:index');
      return [sts,date];
      } else{ return null; } }
```

By using GEE methods it changes to:

```
  var time = TmeanDay.get('Day_view_time');
    //print('time', time);
  var hours = ee.Number(time).floor().divide(1).int();
  var minutes = ee.Number(time).subtract(hours).multiply(60).round().int();
  var result = hours.format('%02d').cat(':').cat(minutes.format('%02d')).cat(':00');
  var systemTimeStart = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd ');
  var sts = ee.String(systemTimeStart).cat(ee.String(result));
  //print('sts:', sts);
  var date = image.get('system:index');
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(time, [sts, date], null);
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9ca085061fab6357f50456995479f0a) with above lines, result looks as follows:

[image]

No more "String (Error) Number.floor: Parameter 'input' is required" instead of desired **null** string; as it can be observed in above picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I use another reducers and put them into returned list I still recieve the error "Invalid string length". Can you please look at this [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/873661392ba4d934f3fdd086480180f2)

Comment: Sorry, but it is another question completely different. I  reviewed your script at the link and I know where the problem is. You should mark this question as accepted and post as a new question the script in your link. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, try to avoid **getInfo()** because it freezes the GUI. I modified your script again for avoiding the use of  **getInfo()**. The script speeds up. Modifications are including here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9ca085061fab6357f50456995479f0a

Comment: wow. now it runs like a wind:) I'm new in programming, will ask Google about GUI xD Thanx for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, the problem in your script at the link is the getInfo. Fix it as in my above link and the script will work like a charm. You don't need to post another question. This is the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/240f37e4b54876c2819e301868661636